# Qual seria o código para simular o inverso do tab

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Tenho um projeto em que eu abro um form dentro do outro, e com isso nos forms secundários o evento OnKeyDown em vez de ir para ir para os do forms secundários estão indo para o form Principal, mais se eu aperto tab na telas segundarias ele vai normal, então resolvi simular o tab.
Sei que o Código para simular `keybd_event(VK_TAB, 0, 0, 0);` mais como fazer para simular o inverso?

```
procedure TfrmAndamento.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin

  if ((key=VK_RETURN) or (key=VK_DOWN)) and not((Sender is TMemo) or (Sender is TComboBox) or (Sender is TDBComboBox) or (Sender is TDBGrid))
  then
    selectNext(ActiveControl,True,True); // <= aqui o sistema da erro pois o ActiveControl sempre vem o objeto que não era o correspondente
end;
```

Comment: Sinceramente não entende o por que de fechar a pergunta?
"... mas se a sua pergunta tem a ver com..."
- um problema específico de programação - OK
- um algoritmo de software  
- ferramentas comuns entre programadores, quando aplicadas no desenvolvimento de software
- problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software - OK
dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicadas ao desenvolvimento de software - OK 
- Não é um pergunta duplicada  - OK
Não tem dizendo que tem que todos os pontos acima.

Comment: É o costume no Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você quer simular o Shift + Tab? Experimente dessa forma:

```
  keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, 0, 0);               // pressiona o Shift
  keybd_event(VK_TAB, 0, 0, 0);                 // pressiona o Tab
  keybd_event(VK_TAB, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);   // solta o Tab
  keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // solta o Shift
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: vou testar aqui. Valeu!

Comment: Velho funcionou mesmo. Muito top!! Valeu